# Redirect from domain name to a dotted quad hosted box

Tags: php, hosting, dns

I have a php server that is running my domain name.  For testing purposes I am running an asp.net on a dotted quad IP. I am hoping to link them together via either PHP or some kind of DNS/`.htaccess` voodoo.

So if I go to `www.mydomain.com/test` it redirects (but keeps the url  of (`www.mydomain.com/test`) in the browser's address bar and the pages are served by the dotted quad IP asp.net box.

Comment: Please tell us, which software you use for the web server! Apache? IIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of pointing `www.yourdomain.com/test` at your test server, why not use `test.yourdomain.com`?

Assuming you have access to the DNS records for `yourdomain.com`, you should just need to create an A record mapping `test.yourdomain.com` to your test server's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible, if I understand what you're getting at.

You have a PHP server with your domain pointing to it. You also have a separate ASP.NET server that only has an IP address associated with it, no domain.

Is there any drawback to simply pointing your domain name to your ASP.NEt box?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make `www.mydomain.com/test` serve a HTML file which has a single frame with the plain IP address. However, this means that the URL in the (awesome) address bar always stays exactly the same, even if you click a link on the displayed page. (You can avoid this by adding `target=_top` in the `href`, but this would require some modifications to your "asp.net".)

The only other way I can think of is to make `www.mydomain.com` act as proxy. That is, at `/test` it has a script or something that gets the page from your "asp.net" and forwards it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a proxy, but I think Will Harris's answer is the best - use a subdomain.  Much simpler, and it'll get rid of issues with relative links as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the sub-domain idea is the best, but if for some reason it doesn't work for you you could also have the php page at /test proxy requests to a URL at the dotted quad machine (using fopen to access the dotted quad URL).